# Create a titlepage: package .sty

Tags: packages, titles

I would like to create a package (`.sty`) for a titlepage. I followed this guide https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation from which I took the following two codes: the first code is the package called `columbidaeTitle.sty`, the second code is the document where the package, earlier created, is loaded.

columbidaeTitle.sty

```
% Copyright note: This package defines how titles should
% be typeset at the columbidae University
% Please check for updates
\ProvidesPackage{columbidaeTitle}[2015/08/10 v.01 an
example package^^J for wikibooks]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\project}[1]{\gdef\@project{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@project}{Final Year Project}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@supervisor}{\texttt{\string\supervisor} currently
not set. Please fix this.}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
{\raggedleft%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-16x9}\par
}\vspace{1cm}
    \centering
{\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
\vspace{1cm}
{\scshape\Large\@project\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{1.5cm}
{\huge\bfseries\@title\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large\itshape\@author\unskip\strut\par}
\vfill
supervised by\par
\@supervisor\unskip\strut\par

\vfill

{\large \@date\par}
\end{titlepage}
}
\endinput
```

Document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{columbidaeTitle}
\supervisor{Dr. James Miller}
\project{Bachelor Thesis}
\author{A LaTeX enthusiast}
\title{Why i want to be a duck}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Ducks are awesome}
\end{document}
```

I have an issue. I would like the whole document to have this margin:

```
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
```

except for the titlepage, for which I would like to have

```
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
```

I tried to insert `\RequirePackage{geometry}` in the `columbidaeTitle.sty` file and then

```
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
```

but it didn't work. How can I make?

Comment: try `\begin{titlepage}\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
...
\restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}
`

Comment: But since the titlepage is quite static, you can use an extra document and just include the pdf as stated in .... well, it was somewhere. Isn't that written on that wiki page?

Comment: By the way, packing up a new package is only a good idea, if you have a standard page and you want to save your colleagues some time. Else, *c.f.* [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Comment: This is my first time trying to create (copy and paste it truthfully) a simple package. I would not like to create it inside the document but I wish to create this package. Anyway: I tried `\RequirePackage{geometry}
`, then `\begin{titlepage}\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm} ... \restoregeometry \end{titlepage}` and in document `.tex` I inserted 
`\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}` but I get an error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.`

Comment: Yes of course, you cannot load the document with different options. Use `\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}`

Comment: I have to say that your bindingoffset is quite large, and that omitting it on the title seems to be more than strange to me. The title will be moved strange into the left margin. Do you want that?

Comment: I inserted `\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}` in the `.sty` file and only `\usepackage{geometry}` in the `.tex` file. Now I do not get any error. Is it correct? I am going to think about what you said about the binding offset.

Comment: I did not read your comment well: are you saying to put in the `.tex` file `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}` and in `.sty` file just `\usepackage{geometry}`?

Comment: Do `\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}{}{\RequirePackage[pass]{geometry}}`. If `geometry` has already been loaded, OK, otherwise, load it so it doesn't harm the page parameters, but you'll have `\newgeometry` available.

Comment: Putting that line into the package really only makes sense, if the package is used by more than one author.

Comment: I got lost. Putting `\RequirePackage{geometry}\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}` in the `.sty` file and `\usepackage{geometry}` in the `.tex` file works. Putting `\usepackage{geometry}` in the `.sty` file and `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm} ` in the `.tex` file also works. I did not understand how to make the egreg's solution works.

Comment: Marco, does your titlepage change every two days? If not, and this is *just* for you, set up a new document with your current preamble and save the title as one single pdf which you include in your document.

Comment: By this point, even if I think I will include  the titlepage as you suggested, I would like to understand how to solve it. Particularly, could you tell me: even if these two following solutions do not give me errors when compiling, are they both correct? `\RequirePackage{geometry}\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}` in the `.sty` file and `\usepackage{geometry}` in the `.tex` file works. `\usepackage{geometry}` in the `.sty` file and `\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}` in the `.tex` file works.

Comment: You can load the package just once with a specific option set. Having a package makes sense if used by many, as i said multiple times. That also means, the geometry for the titlepage is fixed by the author of the package (right now, that is you). You as the author wants to use apckage `geometry` to set the margins on the titlepage. Now egreg's line drops in: Test if the package is already loaded, if so, ddon't do anything. If not, load package geometry without changing the default margins (`pass`) because that would change the rest of the document. `\newgeometry` can be used savely.

Comment: Now suppose, `geometry` wasn't already loaded at load time of the bird package ... It will be afterwards. If your normal preamble now tries to load `geometry` with a specific set of options, you will get the option clash you mentioned earlier. You now have to use `\geometry{bottom=2cm}`.

Comment: Or in other words, as a package author you have to be aware of the crazy things the package user comes up with, trying to think a few steps ahead. Like chess. As a normal user, needing this just once, you should not bend your mind three steps ahead to understand a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: I would like now to set the package as it was used by other users. I can't figure out how to make the egreg's solutions works.

Comment: Put that line into the package file *before* setting up the titlepage.

Comment: The wikibook pages tates that providing a titlepage as a package is something for experienced users. Sorry, please don't get me wrong, but ... I don't think you have the needed experience yet to provide something other people rely on.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I would have liked to create this titlepage as if somebody, besides me, had to use it, but not for real. Just for fun, to learn something new. However, I have not tried to use that line. I think it will be tough (for me, as I do not have experience) to make it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just load `geometry` conditionally. Of course the documentation should make it clear that the package *must* be loaded after `geometry`, if this package is used. A test for this could be added.

### `columbidaeTitle.sty`

```
% Copyright note: This package defines how titles should
% be typeset at the columbidae University
% Please check for updates

\ProvidesPackage{columbidaeTitle}[2015/08/10 v.01 an example package^^J for wikibooks]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}{}{\RequirePackage[pass]{geometry}}

\newcommand*{\project}[1]{\gdef\@project{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@project}{Final Year Project}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@supervisor}{\texttt{\string\supervisor} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
  \newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
  {\raggedleft\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-16x9}\par}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \centering
  {\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
  \vspace{1cm}
  {\scshape\Large\@project\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\huge\bfseries\@title\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{2cm}
  {\Large\itshape\@author\unskip\strut\par}
  \vfill
  supervised by\par
  \@supervisor\unskip\strut\par
  \vfill
  {\large \@date\par}
  \end{titlepage}
}
\endinput
```

### `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{columbidaeTitle}
\supervisor{Dr. James Miller}
\project{Bachelor Thesis}
\author{A LaTeX enthusiast}
\title{Why i want to be a duck}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Ducks are awesome}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Output if the call of `geometry` in `test.tex` is removed

[image]

Comment: Title and chapters sound suspiciously like the ones in my thesis... `:)`